# Tomcat CORS: Preflight successful, but actual request fails with 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, apache, google-chrome, tomcat, cors

My REST services are deployed under Tomcat 7.0.64 (http://localhost:8080/xxx). I invoke these services from using a JavaScript library sourced by HTML pages. These HTML pages are served from another orgin (http://localhost:9090/html/yyy.html).

To enable cross origin requests, on server, I have configured CORSFilter in web.xml as follows:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,X-CUSTOM1,X-CUSOM2,X-CUSTOM3</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,X-CUSTOM3</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

From following output from RequestDumper, you can notice that preflight request from browser has received successful response(200). However, the actual request that followed failed with 403 Forbidden:

**Preflight Request and Response**

```
http-apr-8080-exec-6 ===============================================================
http-apr-8080-exec-8 START TIME        =26-Sep-2015 21:28:53
http-apr-8080-exec-8         requestURI=/xxxx/zzzz
http-apr-8080-exec-8           authType=null
http-apr-8080-exec-8  characterEncoding=null
http-apr-8080-exec-8      contentLength=-1
http-apr-8080-exec-8        contentType=null
http-apr-8080-exec-8        contextPath=/xxxx
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=host=localhost:8080
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=connection=keep-alive
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=pragma=no-cache
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=cache-control=no-cache
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=access-control-request-method=POST
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=origin=http://localhost:9090
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.42 Safari/537.36
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=access-control-request-headers=x-custom1, x-custom2
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=accept=*/*
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=referer=http://localhost:9090/html/yyyy.html
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, sdch
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.8,ta;q=0.6
http-apr-8080-exec-8             locale=en_US
http-apr-8080-exec-8             method=OPTIONS
http-apr-8080-exec-8           pathInfo=null
http-apr-8080-exec-8           protocol=HTTP/1.1
http-apr-8080-exec-8        queryString=null
http-apr-8080-exec-8         remoteAddr=127.0.0.1
http-apr-8080-exec-8         remoteHost=127.0.0.1
http-apr-8080-exec-8         remoteUser=null
http-apr-8080-exec-8 requestedSessionId=null
http-apr-8080-exec-8             scheme=http
http-apr-8080-exec-8         serverName=localhost
http-apr-8080-exec-8         serverPort=8080
http-apr-8080-exec-8        servletPath=/zzzz
http-apr-8080-exec-8           isSecure=false
http-apr-8080-exec-8 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
http-apr-8080-exec-8 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
http-apr-8080-exec-8           authType=null
http-apr-8080-exec-8        contentType=null
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=Access-Control-Allow-Origin=http://localhost:9090
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=Access-Control-Max-Age=10
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=Access-Control-Allow-Methods=POST
http-apr-8080-exec-8             header=Access-Control-Allow-Headers=content-type,x-custom1,access-control-request-headers,accept,access-control-request-method,x-custom2,origin,x-custom3,x-requested-with
http-apr-8080-exec-8         remoteUser=null
http-apr-8080-exec-8             status=200
http-apr-8080-exec-8 END TIME          =26-Sep-2015 21:28:53
http-apr-8080-exec-8 ===============================================================
```

**Actual Request and Response - That failed with 403 Forbidden**

```
http-apr-8080-exec-9 START TIME        =26-Sep-2015 21:28:53
http-apr-8080-exec-9         requestURI=/xxxx/zzzz
http-apr-8080-exec-9           authType=null
http-apr-8080-exec-9  characterEncoding=null
http-apr-8080-exec-9      contentLength=0
http-apr-8080-exec-9        contentType=null
http-apr-8080-exec-9        contextPath=/xxxx
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=host=localhost:8080
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=connection=keep-alive
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=content-length=0
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=pragma=no-cache
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=cache-control=no-cache
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=origin=http://localhost:9090
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=x-custom1=aaaaa
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=x-custom2=bbbbb
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.42 Safari/537.36
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=accept=*/*
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=referer=http://localhost:9090/html/yyyy.html
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=accept-encoding=gzip, deflate
http-apr-8080-exec-9             header=accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.8,ta;q=0.6
http-apr-8080-exec-9             locale=en_US
http-apr-8080-exec-9             method=POST
http-apr-8080-exec-9           pathInfo=null
http-apr-8080-exec-9           protocol=HTTP/1.1
http-apr-8080-exec-9        queryString=null
http-apr-8080-exec-9         remoteAddr=127.0.0.1
http-apr-8080-exec-9         remoteHost=127.0.0.1
http-apr-8080-exec-9         remoteUser=null
http-apr-8080-exec-9 requestedSessionId=null
http-apr-8080-exec-9             scheme=http
http-apr-8080-exec-9         serverName=localhost
http-apr-8080-exec-9         serverPort=8080
http-apr-8080-exec-9        servletPath=/zzzz
http-apr-8080-exec-9           isSecure=false
http-apr-8080-exec-9 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
http-apr-8080-exec-9 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
http-apr-8080-exec-9           authType=null
http-apr-8080-exec-9        contentType=text/plain
http-apr-8080-exec-9         remoteUser=null
http-apr-8080-exec-9             status=403
http-apr-8080-exec-9 END TIME          =26-Sep-2015 21:28:53
http-apr-8080-exec-9 ===============================================================
```

I am using Chrome as my browser.

I am wondering, when a preflight request is successful, is it possible for the actual response to get 403 forbidden?

> Also please note that I have tested sending this same request from
>   Chrome plugin Postman and I could get the expected response
>   successfully without 403 error.

I went through the flow given in: [Tomcat CORSFilter flowchart](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/images/cors-flowchart.png). I am not clear as what is going wrong here. Appreciate your help in solving the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried logging with tomcat in wso2 das 3.10 , but I failed. 
log4j.properties:org.apache.catalina.filters=DEBUG

What's your logging settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had encountered the exact same issue. The solution was quite simple actually.

"There I noticed that the HTTP POST requests are somehow required to have the Content-Type HTTP header filled."

Try adding a Content-Type to your POST request.

Answer (score 1):

To add onto [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430995/7487335), the most likely reason for this working in Postman but not in the browser itself is that Postman is probably automatically adding the `Content-Type` to the request.